# Скобки в сообщении телеграмм бота. Как избавиться

Tags: telegram-bot, типы-данных

Пользуюсь возвратом стринга в текст из списка "%s". При отправке сообщения он возвращает скобки.
Как от них можно избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['list', 'etc']

bot.send_message(1, '{}'.format(a))
>>> ['list', 'etc']

bot.send_message(1, '{}'.format(', '.join(a)))
>>> list, etc
```

`join` возвращает строку, собранную из элементов указанного объекта, поддерживающего итерирование.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло